# Relationship between .bss section size and object/executable file size

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

If I have a C or CPP program written like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bss_section_object[10];
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling the code with gcc/g++,

```
$g++ -save-temps aa.cpp
```

If I check the size of generated object and executable files

```
$ls -ltr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh dinesh    77 Feb 14 12:42 aa.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh dinesh 17283 Feb 14 12:45 aa.ii
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh dinesh   517 Feb 14 12:45 aa.s
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh dinesh  1296 Feb 14 12:45 aa.o
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dinesh dinesh  8592 Feb 14 12:45 a.out
$size a.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1099     544      72    1715     6b3 a.out
$size aa.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     67       0      40     107      6b aa.o
```

Now if I comment the object created on .bss section

```
#include <stdio.h>
//int bss_section_object[10];
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and check the size after compling it:-

```
$ls -ltr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh dinesh    79 Feb 14 12:46 aa.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh dinesh 17256 Feb 14 12:46 aa.ii
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh dinesh   378 Feb 14 12:46 aa.s
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh dinesh  1232 Feb 14 12:46 aa.o
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dinesh dinesh  8552 Feb 14 12:46 a.out
$size a.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1099     544       8    1651     673 a.out
$size aa.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     67       0       0      67      43 aa.o
```

I can see that their size varies based on "bss_section_object" size.

If I read the details of .bss section, then as per wikipedia:-
"The size that BSS will require at runtime is recorded in the object file,
 but BSS (unlike the data segment) doesn't take up any actual space in the
 object file". 
We can see similar description of .bss section in other computer science
books as well.

Now, If the .bss section doesn't take up any space in object file, then why
is the size of object as well as executable file changing based on size of
object created on .bss section?

Can someone please explain the details about it?

Comment: Demonstrate what you're claiming?  Create two programs with different sizes for your `bss_section_object` (or one program that takes a `#define` to control the size of the object).  Show the different outputs from `ls` and `size`.

Comment: No optimization options? Debug builds may very well initialize data which is formally uninitialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are perfectly right when saying :

> "The size that BSS will require at runtime is recorded in the object file, but BSS (unlike the data segment) doesn't take up any actual space in the object file"

Because uninitialized data is placed in the `.bss` section of the program, which is of type `SHT_NOBITS` (see the [`elf(5)` manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?elf(5))).
To convince yourself that this section doesn't takes up any space in the ELF file, try `readelf -Wl /bin/ls` and look at the fourth segment :

```
[...]
LOAD 0x01a310 0x000000000061a310 0x000000000061a310 0x0012f0 0x002010 RW  0x200000
[...]
`03  .init_array .fini_array .jcr .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
```

You can see that it contains (among others), the `.bss` section, and has file size `0x12f0` but memory size `0x2010`. The difference is the size of the `.bss` section.

This section is not included in the file because the associated memory region will be zeroed out at program startup, and it would be unnecessary to store zeros in the file.

#### You're right, but your test is wrong

In the example you give, given that you disable optimization and debugger symbols, the difference you see in file size may be explained by the symbol table, and not by the change of the `.bss` section size.

Here's an experiment you can reproduce :

```
you$ cat main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef USE_BSS
int bss_section_object[10];
#endif
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
you$ g++ -O0 main.cpp -o without.elf
you$ g++ -DUSE_BSS -O0 main.cpp -o with.elf
you$ ls -l *.elf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 you you 8505 Feb 14 10:00 with.elf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 you you 8462 Feb 14 10:00 without.elf
```

At this point, you may believe that changing the .bss section size affects the file size, but in fact the difference is due to the additional symbol `bss_section_object` in the symbol table (which you can remove using the `strip command`) :

```
you$ readelf -WS with.elf > with && readelf -WS without.elf > without
you$ diff with without
30c30
<   [25] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000601040 00102c 000048 00  WA  0   0 32
---
>   [25] .bss              NOBITS          000000000060102c 00102c 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
33,34c33,34
<   [28] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 0018e8 000618 18     29  45  8
<   [29] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 001f00 000239 00      0   0  1
---
>   [28] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 0018e8 000600 18     29  45  8
>   [29] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 001ee8 000226 00      0   0  1
# Yep, the .symtab and .strtab are also different
you$ strip *.elf
you$ ls -l *.elf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 you you 6232 Feb 14 10:06 with.elf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 you you 6232 Feb 14 10:06 without.elf
```

Yay ! By removing the symbol table section `.symtab` (it its associated string table `.strtab`), you end up with the same file size, but different `.bss` section sizes, which is what you expected.